# How to connect Android Studio app to Firebase for a team

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, github

I have started to work on an app with my team by using Android Studio. I was trying to connect it to Firebase, and everything was fine. But it seems that I shouldn't push google-services.json file to GitHub, bc of the API key.

So, what do I have to do, to connect the app to Firebase for all members of the team?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The information from the `google-services.json` file will also be present in your compiled application, so there's no concern putting it in source control (see the question I linked). It *is* common however for each developer to use their own project so you don't get into each other's way, which *might* be a reason to not put a default google-services.json` into version control.